# Unable to start the browser with selenium on python (windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, selenium

I have chrome at this `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application` path, and driver at this `C:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe` path, and i am trying to run this script but its not starting the browser, it doesn't even show any error or exception.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

I even have tried to add the driver's path into system variables, but it still doesn't work.

And it's not working with firefox either `driver=webdriver.Firefox()`.

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see errors? Firefox needs [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/)

Comment: i have ran the python file containing this code on cmd.exe, using this command `python3 filename.py`

Comment: you could add `print()` between lines to see which print() will display message and which line will block it.

Comment: you could also run `C:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe` in `cmd.exe` to see if it doesn't get some error message. It runs server which gives access to browser and maybe system (firewall, antivirus) blocks this server.

Comment: i have tried running it with this command `python filename.py`, and it's working. maybe selenium module is not up to date with python 3.

Comment: BTW: `chromedriver.exe` in `cmd.exe` will not run Chrome but it should display something like this `Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.`

Comment: driver server is running fine without any error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I am happy!

Comment: every Python (2.7, 3.6, 3.7) has own folder with modules and it need to install Selenium separatelly. You may have to install it `python3 -m pip install --update selenium`

Comment: i'll try this then, thanks man. i had installed it with this command `pip install selenium`.

Comment: `pip` can install for `python`. For `python3` you should have `pip3` or you can use `python3 -m pip`